# how do I substitute elements in a hash using ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, hash, substitution

I have JSON hash of indeterminate key names and field values to which I would want to substitute string or sub-string in the values.  For example:

`{"COLLECTION"=>{"$"=>"biblestudy"},
 "JSON"=>{"$"=>"{ \"type\" : \"reaction\", \"verse_reaction\": \"That our lives should be one of giving life\", \"verse_key\" : \"109dc58b8020681e\" }"},
 "KEY"=>{"$"=>"key.verse_reaction"},
 "REPLACE-KEY"=>{"$"=>"replace-key"}}`

I could want to replace `replace-key` with some value stored in a has `{"replace-key" : "this is the replacement"}`

I have tried the following:

`json_element.map { |k,v| v.map { |k1,v1| v1.replace_hash(hash={"hope" => "life" })} }`

I created `replace_hash` as a method for `String`:

```
 def replace_hash(hash=nil)

  if hash.present?

    hash.each do | key, substitute |

      self.sub! key, substitute
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_element.map { |k,v|  v['$'].replace_hash(hash = @replace_hash) }`

I played around with the above and got it to work.